# Google earth api: how to execute handler when info window is opened

Tags: google-earth, google-earth-plugin

I have a Google earth plugin istance with data loaded from a kml file.
The kml contains polygons, when clicking on the polygon the baloon with the contenent of the  tag is opened.

How can I attach an handler to the opening of the baloon, this handler will then create a custom baloon and stop the default event.

I think it should be something like this, I just don't know what event to listen for!

```
google.earth.addEventListener("SOMETHING", 'click', function(event) {
//Code to create custom baloon
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are listening for 'click', what you need to know is what to listen for click from.

In this case I guess you want to listen for clicks on any polygons.

To do this set up a generic listener for all clicks, then test if the click is on a polygon, if so then cancel the default behaviour and display a custom balloon.

e.g.

```
google.earth.addEventListener(ge.getWindow(), 'click', function(e) { 
    if (e.getTarget().getType() == 'KmlPlacemark' && 
    e.getTarget().getGeometry().getType() == 'KmlPolygon') {
        // Prevent the default balloon from appearing.
        e.preventDefault();

        // create a custom balloon attached to the target
        var balloon = ge.createHtmlStringBalloon('');
        balloon.setFeature(e.getTarget());
        balloon.setContentString("custom baloon!");
        ge.setBalloon(balloon);
    }
});
```